# Can't start xampp's mysql , after installing MySQL server in windows 10

Tags: mysql, xampp

Yesterday I downloaded MySQL server on my windows 10 PC. It worked well. But after that when I started XAMPP and tried to start mysql, it did not. I have tried to change the port of xampp's mysql. But it does not work and still mysql is not starting. I don't know any other solution. Tell me if anyone knows.

This is error log

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-02-14 16:27:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows 
interlocked functions
2020-02-14 16:27:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-14 16:27:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-14 16:27:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-14 16:27:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-02-14 16:27:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size 
= 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-02-14 16:27:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer 
pool
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are 
active.
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for 
temporary tables
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 
'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file 
full; Please wait ...
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' 
size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 
1234989; transaction id 1368
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\x 
ampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-14 16:27:06 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: I think that MySQL servers - standalone and from XAMPP - interfere. And now either MySQL service from XAMPP is running (which prevents standalone server running) or XAMPP's MySQL instance damages some data for standalone server. Show error log.

Comment: @Akina, am I able to use only one of them